# How to make VSCode automatically generate space before opening curly brackets (C/C++)?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

What it is now:

```
int main(){

}
```

How I want it to be:

```
int main() {

}
```

When I write code in Eclipse, a space is created **automatically** *before the curly bracket* that opens the block. But I just can't get VSCode to work the same way... I tried to change the settings and saw that there is such a setting but it still does not automatically generate a space.

I'm very desperate to know how I can enable this in VSCode.

[image]

**[Open for question editing suggestions]**